# mySQL multiple select from two tables (filtering)

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I have two tables at my DB that i want to make a select query
First one keeps the product id (int) and if the product is published
The second table keeps the filters, and matches with id_product (which is basicaly the product_id from Products) . at id_filter_child we have the value

products

```
product_id,
published
```

filters

```
id_pro_fil,
id_product,
id_filter_child
```

My tables now are:

products

```
1     yes
2     yes
3     no
```

filters

```
10   1    4
11   1    5
12   2    4
13   2    6
14   2    7
```

So that is my DB at the moment.
From input i have the filters that i want to search 
So i want to select all products with filter=4
i use:

```
SELECT * FROM products,filters
WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product
     AND products.published='1'
     AND filters.id_filter_child='4'
```

That one works!

Now i need to select all products with filter 4 AND 6.
I use:

```
SELECT * FROM products,filters
WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product
     AND products.published='1'
     AND filters.id_filter_child='4'
     AND filters.id_filter_child='6'
```

but i doesnt work
(as a result i would want the product with id=2)

Some help please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all products, then there is no reason to also include the filters.  One approach is to use an aggregation and `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p JOIN
     filters f
     ON p.product_id = f.id_product
WHERE p.published = '1'
GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING SUM(f.id_filter_child = '4') > 0 AND
       SUM(r.id_filter_child = '6') > 0
```

This returns product that have both filter 4 and filter 6.

Note that I also fixed the query to use proper, explicit `join` syntax.

I like this method for "set-within-sets" subqueries, because it is quite general.  You can add another filter to the `HAVING` clause with a similar condition.  You could get everything with 4 but not 6 by changing the second `> 0` to `= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filters ON p.product_id = f.id_product
WHERE p.published='1' AND f.id_pro_fil IN (4,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your logic:

```
 AND filters.id_filter_child='4'
 AND filters.id_filter_child='6'
```

You're requiring every `filter_child` in the database to have two **DIFFERENT** values at the same time. "this record must be a banana and a ferrari simutaneously"

You want an `OR` instead:

```
AND ((filter_child = '4') OR (filter_child = '6'))
```

(note the extra brackets), or more compactly:

```
AND (filter_child IN ('4', '6'))
```

--- comment followup

If you need both values to be attached to a record,t hen you'll have to use some extra logic:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(filters.id_filter_child IN ('4', '6')) AS count
FROM products,filters
WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product
     AND products.published='1'
     AND filters.id_filter_child IN ('4', '6')
GROUP BY filters.id_filter_child
HAVING count = 2
```

The `where` returns only the records that have either `4` or `6`  for filter_child - this will catch records that have at least ONE of those two values. The `COUNT(..)` + `GROUP` + `HAVING` business will then filter out all but those records that have BOTH of the values.

Comment: i still need the product to have both 4 and 6
if i use the OR i get wrong result
i need the product that has 4 AND 6...

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR or IN

```
SELECT * FROM products,filters 
  WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product 
      AND  products.published='1' 
      AND (filters.id_filter_child='4' OR filters.id_filter_child='6')

SELECT * FROM products,filters 
  WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product 
      AND  products.published='1' 
      AND filters.id_filter_child IN (4,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should **OR** in between the two conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM products,filters
WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product
     AND products.published='1'
     AND filters.id_filter_child='4'
     OR filters.id_filter_child='6'
```

but to make your sql smaller and simpler you can use **IN** operator also:

```
SELECT * FROM products,filters
WHERE products.product_id=filters.id_product
     AND products.published='1'
     AND filters.id_filter_child IN(4,6)
```